# What are the pros & cons of these kinds of plugins?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each one:

```
 $.fn.hello = function() {  
    $(this).append('<div id="hello">Hello world</div>');
    $(this).delegate('#hello', 'click', function(){
        alert("Hello you clicker");
    });
 } 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').createHello();
});
```

**Or:**

```
 $.hello= function() {  
    $('body').append('<div id="hello">Hello world</div>');
    $('body').delegate('#hello', 'click', function(){
        alert("Hello you clicker");
    });
 } 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.createHello();
});
```

?

Comment: one of the disadvantages is that neither will work ;)

Comment: that's not possible, considering you named your function `hello` and you're calling `createHello` unless there's code you're not showing us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage of that first is that you can use `$(this)`, which you can't use in the second one, so you would have to change it everytime you would want to place it in different location

Comment: Are there any advantages to the 2nd one?